# Accessing to a nonlocal variable by the following limitations

Tags: python, function, increment

I am trying to figure out a situation in  a exercise in Python
The question is:

Define two functions:

- p: prints the value of a variable
- q: increments the variable
- Initial value of the variable is 0

Limitations:

- Variable is not located in the global environment, and the only way
  to change it is by invoking q()
- The only bindings introduced to global environment by the code are for p and q.

The following code will describe the situation:

```
# >>> p()
# 0
# >>> q()
# >>> q()
# >>> p()
# 2
# >>> print([k for k,v in globals().items() if v==2]) 
## checks that a variable with the value ‘2’ does not exist in the global environment.
# []
```

I would like to get some suggestions how should I solve it.
Thanks.

Comment: Clear up what you are asking .

Comment: A global variable with a value incremented by 1 will fit the tests...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Disclaimer: this is not a terribly serious answer.  Fits the specifications laid out in the OP though!

```
def p():
    print(p.__dict__.get('smuggled_value',0))

def q():
    p.smuggled_value = getattr(p,'smuggled_value',0) + 1
```

More-serious answer: this question is trivial if you allow `p` or `q` to have arguments.  Otherwise you need to do some pretty hacky things, or use globals.

**edit**: explanation as requested:

In python, everything is an object, including functions.  Objects with a `__dict__` attribute allow attribute assignment with the `object.attribute` syntax.  Normally you only do this kind of attribute assignment to `class` members, but functions permit it too.  So I take advantage of this since you're only allowed to create `p` and `q`.

Note that you should really NOT code like this in reality.  As you can tell from your confusion, this way of coding is in *no way* readable.  Provide arguments to your functions so they're human-readable.

Comment: yea i know its really hard maybe impossible to do it without cheat .  anyway your answer is usful and solved the problem . but if u can pliz explain to me how it work becuz i dont know about those function u used. thanks

Comment: @RefaelOknin I edited in an explanation.

Answer (score 2):

You could define the variable in the local scope of a function:

```
def p():
    i = [0]
    def p():
        return i[0]
    def q():
        i[0] += 1
    return p, q

p, q = p()

print(p())
# 0
q()
q()
print(p())
# 2
print([k for k,v in globals().items() if v==2]) 
# []
```

---

In Python3, you could use the `nonlocal` statement so you could make `i` an int instead of a list:

```
def p():
    i = 0
    def p():
        return i
    def q():
        nonlocal i
        i += 1
    return p, q
```

Comment: I had this thought as well, but the OP specifies `Variable is not located in the global environment, and the only way to change it is by invoking q()`, and I don't think your `p()` fits that contract.

Comment: Good point. I'll post a different solution which addresses that point.

Comment: but make_pq is still in globals... ("The only bindings introduced to global environment by the code are for p and q")

Comment: With your first solution you need to add `del make_pq` to satisfy the requirement that no other names are added to the global environment. Or just name it `p` or `q` and overwrite it.

Comment: Thanks for the correction, @Duncan and Don.

Comment: your code in python 3 not answer the question becuz global dont know who is q

Answer (score 0):

This is a closure-based version that never introduces any symbols other than `p` and `q` to the global scope:

```
@apply
def p():
    x = [0]
    def p():
        print x[0]
    return p

def q():
    p.func_closure[0].cell_contents[0] += 1
```

It's definitely more on the "hacky" side rather than the "serious answer" side, but on the other hand, so are your requirements. ;-)

---

I'd also say that it's impossible to strictly satisfy the requirement that...

> the only way to change it is by invoking q()

because in this example you could just manually do what `q` does internally.

(Or you could exploit your interpreter's implementation details, declare a `ctypes` pointer and do even nastier hacks on memory level...)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe q can replace the p function each time it's called:

```
p = lambda: 0

def q():
    global p
    value = p() + 1
    p = lambda: value
```

(although it doesn't quite follow the spec -- there isn't actually any variable being incremented)

Answer (score 0):

Since no one posted a class-based solution so far:

```
class _pq(object):
    _x = 0
    @classmethod
    def p(cls):
        print cls._x
    @classmethod
    def q(cls):
        cls._x += 1

p = _pq.p
q = _pq.q
del _pq
```

Answer (score 0):

Got it, my final answer. Only introduces p and q into the namespace, never changes them. The variable is in the default argument of a lambda that's only invoked once, without arguments, and that returns the functions. We avoid putting operator in the global namespace (for operator.setitem) with __import__.

```
p, q = (lambda i=[0]: 
    (lambda: i[0], 
     lambda: __import__('operator').setitem(i, 0, i[0]+1))
)()
```

I think this solution fits the problem best, e.g. there is no way to change the variable apart from calling q, and it doesn't introduce anything unnecessary into the global namespace.
It feels more like Javascript than Python though :-)

Comment: "there is no way to change the variable apart from calling q" ? Well, actually there is - just try this: `q.func_closure[0].cell_contents[0] += 42; print p();`. And actually `p()` is supposed to _print_ the value, not return it.

Comment: OK, I didn't know it was possible to get at a function's closure, thanks. Printing isn't much harder than returning so that can be left as an exercise for the reader. I still think this solution is the cleanest... :-)